# Is it safer to load Kernel32.dll with absolute path?

Tags: winapi

I have a driver code with the following line

```
hKernel32DLL = LoadLibrary( "Kernel32.dll" );
```

Now someone reviewed my code and suggested to load the DLL with full path.
I did a quick search online about loading kernel32.dll but no one really use a full path.

Can someone explain to me why I should specify the absolute path of kernel32.dll?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Before we explore the general question let's get one aspect out of the way: Are you only using Kernel32 as an example or is Kernel32 really the only library you want to dynamically link? In most cases this would be unnecessary because Kernel32 is already statically linked to this program (you are calling LoadLibrary which is in Kernel32).

Comment: `kernel32.dll` will already be loaded into your process, so you can just use `GetModuleHandle()` and not worry about the path.

Comment: Probably you need to get the person who made the suggestion to explain their reasoning. They won't be able to do so.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Is that true for _drivers_ as well? Because that is what he seems to be talking about. Always thought they would only have `ntdll`, but of course that is totally guess work ;-)

Comment: @Christian.K LoadLibrary is in kernel32.dll :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter Duh! Of course, stupid me :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is safer to load .DLLs with a full path. Kernel32 is already loaded because you statically linked to `LoadLibrary` so in your specific case it does not matter. (On all versions of Windows except 2000, `CreateProcess` will load Kernel32 into the process before it even starts but this does not apply to other core .DLLs like Gdi32 and User32.)

If you are worried about .DLL hijacking attacks then you can call [`SetDefaultDllDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories) with the `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32` flag, this forces all .DLLs with a relative path to load from the system directory.

Comment: if be exactly - during `CreateProcess` call only exe and *ntdl.dll* is mapped to new process address space. *kernel32.dll* maped already during process intialization by *ntdll.dll* code, when process running. this(load *kernel32.dll*) will be auto done for gui and console subsystem. but not for native subsystem. from another side `CreateProcess` fail for native exe. so in general can say that `CreateProcess` auto load *kernel32.dll* to process, but this is not direct